# Jackson: Ignore empty fields except those that are mandatory with respect to the project

Tags: java, json, jackson

Following is a POJO class (one of the classes at a certain level of nesting), an object of which, I'm serializing into a JSON using Jackson.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Attribute {

    private String label;
    private String name;        // Mandatory
    private String description; // Mandatory
    private String type;        // Mandatory
    private Boolean hidden;
    private Boolean important;
    ...
```

Using `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)` to only include fields that have values that are not `null` or empty. The issue is that the fields `name`, `description` and `type` are mandatory, that is, they must be present in the generated JSON even if they are `null` or empty. When these fields are provided, I have no problem. But when they are not provided,

instead of this -

```
"attributes" : [ 
    {
        "type" : "Text",
        "hidden" : false,
        "important" : false,
        ...
```

I want this -

```
"attributes" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "",
        "description" : "",
        "type" : "Text",
        "hidden" : false,
        "important" : false,
        ...
```

Fields `label`, `name`, and `description` are empty in the above case. Also, the class which "has" attributes has it in the form -

```
List<Attribute> attributes;
```

That is why, the above JSON is like that.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You can apply `@JsonInclude` to a specific field.

Comment: @chrylis That will be too much as I have only some fields that are mandatory among 20-30 odd fields. Code would become horrible looking.

Comment: How else are you going to indicate to the software which fields are mandatory and which aren't? (I personally would use Groovy and create an annotation collector called `@Mandatory`, but it amounts to the same thing.)

Comment: @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) might do the trick ?

Comment: @Sikorski There are empty fields (non-null) that need not be included.

Comment: I thought optional fields would be null otherwise.

Comment: Most optional fields (mostly strings) are otherwise `null` but not all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the suggestion from @chrylis is what you are looking for. The idea to annotate specific fields with `@JsonInclude` (default value is `JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS`) in field level to override the class level `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)`. Following is an example:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public static class Attribute {

    private String label;
    @JsonInclude
    private String name;        // Mandatory
    @JsonInclude
    private String description; // Mandatory
    @JsonInclude
    private String type;        // Mandatory
```